# How to show/hide jQuery mobile header with two finger tap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, show-hide

I'm making a webapp using phonegap and jquery mobile, and I'm trying to have it where if you tap anywhere on the screen with two fingers, the header with show and hide.

I have a header div on every page with a "header" class. I thought I could just select everything with this class and use jGestures to show/hide (I've never used jGestures before and I'm a rookie with jquery so that might be my problem). And the way I have it now seems like it would only show and hide if you tapped ON the div, whereas I want to be able to tap anywhere on the screen.

Here's what I have:

```
<div class="header" data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Choose Grid</a>
    <h1>Add Images</h1>
    <a href="#choosePage" class="saveGrid" data-icon="check" data-transition="slide" data-theme="b">Done</a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#header").bind("taptwo", function(){
        $("#header").hide();
    }); 
});
```

I know I'm probably way off, but any ideas? Does jQuery mobile have some build in gestures that I should be using instead?

Comment: Remove `.ready` function. Use this only `$(document).on('taptwo', function () { stuff here });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').bind('taptwo', function(){
        $(".header").toggle();
    });
});
```

This sets the event for the whole body of the page. The event will be fired wherever you double tap. Keep in mind that it will interfere with other double tap elements on the same page.

Comment: thanks joe. this seems like it would work, but still no luck after trying this code. i don't know if i'm using jgestures incorrectly or if it's something quirky with jquery mobile that's causing this...

Comment: Have you definitely included `jgestures` on your page?

Comment: Yeah... i just realized i had a random "d" typed at the top of my javascript that was apparently breaking everything. Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @WillRyan If that's the case then you should remove the question as this will not help people in the future.

Comment: @Jasper - His original javascript wasn't working because he was binding to the wrong element. He used my javascript (which solves his issue) but accidentally typed a 'd' which stopped my solution from working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$(".header").bind("taptwo", function(){
    $(".header").hide();
})
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem, you're still attaching the event to the header not the rest of the page.